# How to refresh a connection/device that has no carrier?

Tags: ip, networkmanager, nmcli

I change the MAC address of a connection/device with `nmcli/nmtui`.

Using `ip a` doesn't show the new/cloned MAC address. I tried lots of things with nmcli and nmtui but I keep getting the `no-carrier` error.

- How can I reload it even if it has no carrier?

Comment: How did you change the MAC address? What commands result in "no carrier"? What kind of interface is this?

Comment: Ethernet RJ45, I changed the MAC with `nmcli connection modify enp0s31f6 ethernet.cloned-mac-address AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF`. There is no carrier because there is no cable plugged to it. I want to setup everything before any cable is plugged later.

Comment: What commands result in "no carrier"?

Comment: `nmcli c connect` and the nmtui's `activate connection`. What is the command to reload the connection/device to have the correct mac address?

Comment: I am currently at a loss. To be honest, the aim of my comments was to improve your question (I would incorporate the additional data into the question, by the way). However, I am currently trying as well, with a virtual machine, and even when (virtually) unplugging the cable, I can activate connections without this error message. I thought it's related to the method (auto vs manual), but there is no difference. I use `nmcli c up CONNECTIONNAME` to activate the connection, and I do see the changed MAC address afterwards.

Comment: The problem comes from the ipv4 "Automatic"... I changed to Disable and Ignore (ipv6) and it worked. Thanks!